# Age range of meisei midbar

Tags: death, age, dor-hamidbar

The dor hamidbar was cursed to die before entering the land.  Children under 20 were not included in the curse. Was there an upper limit to the age of those who died in the desert?

Comment: "Children under 20 were not included in the curse." How do you know that?

Answer (score 3):

[Bava Basra 121b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=121b&format=pdf) says that the age of 60 was the upper limit.

> ומשאר שבטים לא עייל....אלא אמר רב אחא בר יעקב לא נגזרה גזירה לא על
>   פחות מבן עשרים ולא על יתר מבן ששים לא על פחות מבן עשרים דכתיב מבן
>   עשרים שנה ומעלה ולא על יתר מבן ששים גמר ומעלה ומעלה מערכין מה להלן יתר
>   מבן ששים כפחות מבן כ' אף כאן יתר מבן ששים כפחות מבן עשרים
>
> Did none of the [members of the] other tribes enter [the promised
>   land]? ....But, said R. Aha b. Jacob, the decree was directed neither
>   against one [who was] under twenty years of age, nor against [one who
>   was] over sixty years of age. [It was directed] neither against [one]
>   under twenty years of age’ — for it is written, from twenty years old
>   and upward; ‘nor against [one] over sixty years of age’ — for ‘and
>   upward’ is deduced from ‘and upward’ [in the section] of valuations,
>   as there, [one] over sixty years of age is like [one] under twenty
>   years of age, so here, one over sixty years of age is like one [who
>   is] under twenty years of age.

( *Soncino translation* )

Comment: +1 for [answering your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!! :)